# Right triangles program errors

Tags: c++

Good day everyone,

I am having a difficult time with a program of mine. It is supposed to compute all possible sides for a right triangles and push them into a vector For example [3,4,5] and [5,12,13].
I tried running this program, but it always lists 3,4,5. Here's the header and function. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Header:
/*
 * triangles.h
 * Header file for triangle class.
*/
// make sure this file is not included multiple times:
#pragma once

#include <vector>
using std::vector;

class triangle {
    public:
        // member functions:
        // constructor:
        triangle(unsigned long a=3, unsigned long b=4, unsigned long c=5):
            s1(a),s2(b),s3(c) {}
        unsigned long perimeter();
        unsigned long area();
        void print();  // prints to standard output
        // member variables:
        // integers for the 3 sides:
        unsigned long s1;
        unsigned long s2;
        unsigned long s3;
};

vector<triangle> findRightTriangles(unsigned long l, unsigned long h);
bool congruent(triangle t1, triangle t2);
bool similar(triangle t1, triangle t2);
```

Function:

```
#include "triangles.h" // import the prototypes for our triangle class.
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
#include <vector>
using std::vector;
#include <algorithm>
using std::sort;



vector<triangle> findRightTriangles(unsigned long l, unsigned long h) {
    // TODO: find all the right triangles with integer sides,
    // subject to the perimeter bigger than l and less than h
    vector<triangle> retval; // storage for return value.
    triangle t1;
    t1.s1=l;
    t1.s3=h;

    for (unsigned long p = 0; p < t1.s3; p++) {
        t1.s2=p;
        if ( p >= t1.s1 && p <= t1.s3 && (((t1.s1*t1.s1)+(p*p)) == (t1.s3*t1.s3))){
            retval.push_back(t1);

            break;
        }
    }

    return retval;
}
```

Comment: @JohnDeters: Why would a copy ctor be needed here?  The compiler-supplied one should be fine, no?

Comment: Sorry, you're right. The default constructor should do a shallow copy of the sides just fine.  Instead, the problem is in your logic. When you call this, the break will cause it to exit after finding a single triangle, and never more than one.  Since you didn't include the calling logic, it's hard to know more.

Comment: BTW, your comments and routine names misled me.  The perimeter isn't "bigger than l but less than h", l and h are the length and height of the legs.  And the routine can only find a single right triangle, never more than one (meaning the vector of responses is misleading as well.) It would make more sense to have this in a smaller `unsigned long findHypotenuse( unsigned long length, unsigned long height);` routine that you would call for each triangle, then make that call from within an outer loop to produce the needed triangles.

Comment: Glad you worked it out. It is a little confusing: there are a couple functions declared in the header which are not member functions.

Comment: rolled back as the code is an essential part of the question.